PowerApps: Column charts with multi-select choice field?
I have an intake SharePoint list where a form is submitted using PowerApps. I'm building a dashboard view within that PowerApp for users to see real-time updates to their existing submissions. There should a filter using: Filter(Submitter.Email = User().Email) on the charts in the dashboard screen.
The SharePoint list has a multi-select SharePoint choice field called "Status". In the PowerApp, I'm trying to show a column chart that has each Status as a bar with the count of requests within each Status.
Use Case: If a user has submitted 5 total requests, 2 are in "Awaiting manager review" status, and the other 3 are in "Manager approved" for example, I want to show a column chart with the Statuses showing 2 and 3 with the corresponding status choices. If we need to show all the other bars as zero, that's fine. It'd be great to only show the bars that have a value.
I've tried a variety of code including AddColumns, GroupBy, Distinct, Count, CountRows, and everytime I try to use any function it errors.
My Status column is named "Status" and the SharePoint list is called 'DCXM Intake'.
